# PHP error debugging in Windows console

Tags: windows, php

I'm using php's `CLI` SAPI on Windows 7 and can't get any error output.

For instance, `echo "hello"` works fine, but `echo $undefined_variable` doesn't output any kind of *Undeifined variable...* error.

I'd love to be able to debug a script on windows but I am afraid I do not know how to set my environment up properly. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first 3 directives listed on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php are what you need, particularly the "display_errors" one.

Comment: Thanks! Obviously, that worked great. Am I under the wrong assumption that this is additional configuration specific to Windows installations? I feel like I did not have to do this when I compiled `5.4` on my Unix machine (unless I was using a `php.ini` file I setup for `5.3.6`).